# Allow connection only over HTTPS in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Was trying to disable any HTTP connections in my Xamarin app.
I set flag in AndroidManifest.xml to disable clear text

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
```

Enabled TLS in "Android options" in my project. But I can still make calls to unsecured websites like
http://neverssl.com/

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Unless you are coding to a quite old Android target, apps should already default to no-cleartext. So must be something else. When you call that unsecured URL, what response to you get? Maybe something in that response object is a clue. Specifically, suppose Android is indeed sending an https request. I believe that website automatically redirects to the corresponding http, then sends a response. Perhaps its up to you to add some custom response handler, that examines the response, and rejects non-secure responses.

Comment: What is the versin of your device? Starting with Android 9 (API level 28) cleartext(non-HTTPS) support is disabled by default. Please check the blog below. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/cleartext-http-android-network-security/

Comment: I figured that I have been using HttpClientHandler. When I changed to native AndroidHandler everything is working ok.